# How to get values in a column of a Dataframe that exist in another Dataframe with same column type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given 2 Dataframe `user_df` and `playlists_df` with same column `User_ID` (both `int64`), how can I get a new dataframe consisting of values from `user_df` where the `User_ID` exists in `playlist_df['User_ID']`?

I tried:

```
users_to_survey = users_df[users_df['User_ID'] in playlists_df['User_ID']]
```

but got:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

`concat` solution seems work but I just want to get specific values from `users_df`, not combining the two dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `in` with Series. Instead, you can use `isin` on a Series to check if any of the values of that Series are in this one:

```
users_to_servey = users_df[playlists_df['User_ID'].isin(users_df['User_ID'])]
```